# How can I manage github branches efficiently?

Tags: git, github

I'm applying `git-flow` on project development. But as time goes, there are tons of branches on my `github`(remote-branch). It seems good idea to keep these old-remote-branch for the future (like, keeping develop history). But it clutters up  my branch list on my local environment. 
[image]

[image]

So dirty!. I want to keep these my old remote-branches on my github, but not to be shown on my local.

And it also makes me hard to think about new branch name. Let say I need to fix or upgrade something about `posts-image`. Then I'm spending so much time which name I should make for my new branch : `posts-image-fix` or other. And finally it is merged (pull request) into `develop` branch. Later, I need to fix the other thing, and this time, should I make branch name something like, `posts-image-fix2`, `posts-image-fix3`...?

Comment: Please copy and paste your console output into the question (and add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line to format it properly), rather than using images.

Comment: Why do you need to keep references to these branches? As you can tell by your first image, the commits are still there, and won't go anywhere if you delete the branch references.

Comment: @ScottWeldon I know that commits gonna be still there even I delete branch, but I want to keep my whole branches too so that I can easily recognize which feature I had implemented in the future.. And also it doens't work : `git branch -D remotes/origin/feature/api`

Comment: @ScottWeldon And about uploading images, I thought that image is more visible and easy to understand what i'm asking. Please, understand it.

Comment: [See this Meta post for information about why you shouldn't post code or console output as images.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332) (Much of it applies to code, but some is equally valid for console output.) In this case, the only thing that is added by using an image is color, which is unnecessary.

Comment: You don't need to keep branches around to tell what was merged if you use the default commit message. See e.g. the message for commit `6beac1a` in your output above (`Merge pull request #14 from rightx2/feature/refactor`).

Comment: The correct syntax to delete a branch is `git branch -d origin/feature/api`. (No need for `-D` unless the branch hasn't been merged. No need for `remotes/` ever.)

Answer (score 1):

As people have said in the comments, keeping the old branches is unnecessary - their entire history is already part of `master`, meaning that you don't lose anything if you delete them.

Since you're using GitHub, you can do this yourself through the UI for your repo. Meanwhile, on your local, you can do something like

```
git branch | xargs git branch -d
```

Which will delete any local branch that has been completely merged.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see--you're asking git to print out all the branches including remote ones, then complaining that it is printing out all the branches including remote ones?

Normally `git branch` will print out only local branches. If you have local copies of remote branches you don't care about, then remove them with `git branch -d`. That will have no effect on the remote.

How to manage branches on your remote is a separate issue. As another answer says, if a branch is merged and done with in general there's little reason to keep it around, so delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the merged branches. If you really have to find them again, generally you don't, use the log message on the merge commit.

You can delete remote branches with `git push remote :branch` as in `git push origin :feature/posts-image`.